# Minimum and maximum length of screen lock passcode?

Tags: 8.1, lock-screen, pin

Does anybody know what are the minimum and maximum lengths of screen lock passcodes on Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: It is easy to determine minimum length by couple of experiments :)

Answer (score 1):

Minimum length can be of 4 digits and max. 16 digits.

Comment: Just curious, do you have a source for this information?